# JavaScript : Convert TimeZone Offset to TimeZone String (Eg: "-5.00" to "CST")

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format, timezone-offset

I am getting a timezone offset as "-5.00" from a service response and I need to format it in the UI as CST. How do I convert this in JavaScript? I searched and am not sure there is any direct method in JavaScript.

Comment: Your question is unclear. "bind the UI as CST" - what does this mean?

Comment: You cannot turn the offset to a timezone name reliably.

Comment: There are many timezones that have a -5:00 offset, including EST ([*Eastern Timezone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) or ET) in the US. In North America, CST would normally be -6:00. There is no standard for naming timezones, though there is the [*IANA timezone database*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Comment: You can't. CST is for the USA, and they have daylight savings. Parts of the year, CST is -5.00. Other parts of the year, it's -6.00. The best you could do is compile your own JSON mapping, then do a key/value lookup to get CST or another timezone abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using Moment. It provides a full timezone library. You may be able to make use of it still depending on your requirements and situation.

http://momentjs.com/timezone/